# Backdrop Image Not Visible When Using Node Group

Tags: compositing-nodes

The backdrop image in the compositor tab is not visible when I usen node group.

I have the viewer node and composite node inside a node group. Outside the group is only the render result node, which is connected to the node group.

Is it possible to have the backdrop image visible with this setup?

Comment: You need to render the image first, then you will see it as a backdrop image in the compositor when the view node is active.

Comment: It would help to see your node setup in and outside the node group

Comment: @L0Lock How can I upload a screenshot here in the comment?

Comment: Do not use comments to post critical information, always put them in your question. There's an "Edit" button at its bottom left corner.